# Can I use outdoor directional antenna for cellular network indoors

Tags: rf, antenna, cellular

There are some pretty cellular Yagi-Uda antennas in the market, but absolute majority of it is outdoor type.

Given I have directional antenna with higher gain than omnidirectional antenna X, and I can direct it to the base station, and mount it indoors, will it perform better than omnidirectional antenna X?

Comment: Will it perform better in terms of what?

Answer (score 2):

Indoor vs outdoor doesn't matter for gain performance.  All that indoor/outdoor means is whether or not it'll stand up to the elements or not.

So yes, an outdoor antenna will work just fine indoors.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a directional antenna, with its obviously higher gain, would be far superior to an omni-directional antenna.

When cell phone performance is bad outdoors, the solution would be a booster having an outdoor directional antenna and omni inside.It would not be advisable to have both the antennas inside the building as that could cause the booster, being a two-way repeater, to malfunction.

If cell phone performance is good outside and only marginally lacking inside,an outdoor directional antenna coupled to an indoor omni would do  as a passive repeater.